# remove excel macros from multiple closed files

Tags: excel, vba

- I have +500 Excel files (*.xls) having macros, all located in same folder.
- I want to remove all macros from these files. Removing macros manually one by one from all files will take too much time.

Is it possible to create a new macro in a separate excel file which will remove all macros from these closed files?

Thanks for your guidance in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you couldnt get Tony's code to work try this version:

1. Change "C:\temp" to the path of your choice
2. All *xls* files will be opened, saved as "orginalfilename_no_code.xlsx" and the prior version will be removed

   ```
   Sub CullCode()
   Dim StrFile As String
   Dim strPath As String

   Dim WB As Workbook
   strPath = "c:\temp\"
   StrFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*")

   With Application
   .DisplayAlerts = False
   .ScreenUpdating = False
   .EnableEvents = False
   End With

   Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        Set WB = Workbooks.Open(strPath & StrFile)
        WB.SaveAs strPath & StrFile & "_no_code.xlsx", 51
        WB.Close False
       Kill strPath & StrFile
       StrFile = Dir
   Loop    

   With Application
   .DisplayAlerts = True
   .ScreenUpdating = True
   .EnableEvents = True
   End With

   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I have coded routines around macro `ListComponentsSingleWbk` to meet your requirement.  I have tested then with a variety of workbooks and I believe they provide the functionality you seek.

Both `ListComponentsCtrl` and `DeleteLinesCtrl` contain the statement `Path = ...`.   You will need to amend these statements to match the path of your folder.

I use macro `ListComponentsSingleWbk` to provide daily backups of the macros I am developing.  I have coded `ListComponentsCtrl` to call `ListComponentsSingleWbk` for every XLS files in a folder.

I suggest you run `ListComponentsCtrl` before you do anything else.  It will create a file with the name “BkUp yymmdd hhmm.txt” where “yymmdd hhmm” represent the current date and time.  Following the run, “BkUp yymmdd hhmm.txt” will contain:

- The name of every workbook it has found.
- The name of every component within a workbook that might contain code.
- If there is code within a component, a list of that code.

Running `ListComponentsCtrl` will ensure you have a complete backup if you discover in a month’s time that you have deleted macros from the wrong workbooks.

`DeleteCodeCtrl` calls `DeleteCodeSingleWbk` for every XLS files in a folder.

`DeleteCodeSingleWbk`:

- Removes all standard and class modules from a workbook.
- Clears any code from the code modules of the worksheets.
- Clears any code from the code module of ThisWorkbook.

---

```
Option Explicit

' This module was built from information scattered across many sites. The
' most useful were:
'   http://vbadud.blogspot.co.uk/2007/05/insert-procedure-to-module-using.html
'   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282830
'   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443716(v=vs.60).aspx
'   http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=32709

' This module needs a reference to:
'                   "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility n.n"

' The security system will probably prevent access to VBComponents unless you:
'   For Excel 2003, from Excel (not VB Editor)
'     Click Tools
'     Click Macro
'     Click Security
'     Click Trusted Publishers
'     Tick Trust access to Visual Basic Project
'   For other versions of Excel search for "programmatic access to Visual Basic project not trusted"

Sub DeleteCodeCtrl()

  Dim FileObj As Object
  Dim FileSysObj As Object
  Dim FolderObj As Object
  Dim Path As String

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False

  ' ### Change to directory containing your Excel workbooks
  ' Note: trailing "\" is assumed by later code
  Path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TestFiles\"

  Set FileSysObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  Set FolderObj = FileSysObj.GetFolder(Path)

  For Each FileObj In FolderObj.Files
    If LCase(Right(FileObj.Name, 4)) = ".xls" Then
      Call DeleteCodeSingleWbk(Path & FileObj.Name)
    End If
  Next

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
Sub DeleteCodeSingleWbk(ByVal WbkName As String)

  Dim CodeLineCrnt As Long
  Dim InxC As Long
  Dim NumCodeLines As Long
  Dim VBC As VBComponent
  Dim VBCType As Long
  Dim VBP As VBProject
  Dim VBMod As CodeModule
  Dim Wbk As Workbook

  Err.Clear
  ' Switch off normal error handling in case attempt to open workbook fails
  On Error Resume Next
  ' Second parameter = False means links will not be updated since not interested in data
  ' Third parameter = False mean open for updating
  Set Wbk = Workbooks.Open(WbkName, False, False)
  ' Restore normal error handling.
  On Error GoTo 0
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    On Error Resume Next
    ' In case partially open
    Wbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
    On Error GoTo 0
  Else

    Set VBP = Wbk.VBProject
    ' Process components in reverse sequence because deleting a component
    ' will change the index numbers of components below it.
    For Each VBC In VBP.VBComponents
      VBCType = VBC.Type
      If VBCType = vbext_ct_StdModule Or VBCType = vbext_ct_ClassModule Then
        ' Component is a module and can be removed
        VBP.VBComponents.Remove VBC
      ElseIf VBCType = vbext_ct_Document Then
        ' Component can have a code module which can be cleared
        Set VBMod = VBC.CodeModule
        NumCodeLines = VBMod.CountOfLines
        If NumCodeLines > 0 Then
          Call VBMod.DeleteLines(1, NumCodeLines)
        End If
      End If
    Next

    Wbk.Close SaveChanges:=True
  End If

End Sub
Sub ListComponentsCtrl()

  Dim BkUpFileObj As Object
  Dim FileObj As Object
  Dim FileSysObj As Object
  Dim FolderObj As Object
  Dim Path As String

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False

  ' ### Change to directory containing your Excel workbooks
  ' Note: trailing "\" is assumed by later code
  Path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TestFiles\"

  Set FileSysObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  Set FolderObj = FileSysObj.GetFolder(Path)

  ' Second parameter = False means existing file will not be overwritten
  ' Third parameter = False means ASCII file will be created.
  Set BkUpFileObj = FileSysObj.CreateTextFile(Path & "BkUp " & Format(Now(), "yymmyy hhmm") & ".txt", _
                    False, False)

  For Each FileObj In FolderObj.Files
    If LCase(Right(FileObj.Name, 4)) = ".xls" Then
      Call ListComponentsSingleWbk(Path & FileObj.Name, BkUpFileObj)
    End If
  Next

  BkUpFileObj.Close

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
Sub ListComponentsSingleWbk(ByVal WbkName As String, ByRef BkUpFileObj As Object)

  Dim CodeLineCrnt As Long
  Dim InxC As Long
  Dim NumCodeLines As Long
  Dim VBC As VBComponent
  Dim VBCType As Long
  Dim VBP As VBProject
  Dim VBMod As CodeModule
  Dim Wbk As Workbook

  Call BkUpFileObj.WriteLine("Workbook " & WbkName)

  Err.Clear
  ' Switch off normal error handling in case attempt to open workbook fails
  On Error Resume Next
  ' Second parameter = False means links will not be updated since not interested in data
  ' Third parameter = True mean open read only
  Set Wbk = Workbooks.Open(WbkName, False, True)
  ' Restore normal error handling.
  On Error GoTo 0
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Call BkUpFileObj.WriteLine("  Unable to open workbook: " & Err.desc)
  Else
    Set VBP = Wbk.VBProject
    For InxC = 1 To VBP.VBComponents.Count
      Set VBC = VBP.VBComponents(InxC)
      VBCType = VBC.Type
      If VBCType = vbext_ct_StdModule Or VBCType = vbext_ct_ClassModule Or _
         VBCType = vbext_ct_Document Then
        ' Component can have a code module
        Set VBMod = VBC.CodeModule
        NumCodeLines = VBMod.CountOfLines
        If NumCodeLines = 0 Then
          Call BkUpFileObj.WriteLine("  No code associated with " & _
                                     VBCTypeNumToName(VBCType) & " " & VBC.Name)
        Else
          Call BkUpFileObj.WriteLine("  Code within " & _
                                     VBCTypeNumToName(VBCType) & " " & VBC.Name)
          For CodeLineCrnt = 1 To NumCodeLines
            Call BkUpFileObj.WriteLine("    " & VBMod.Lines(CodeLineCrnt, 1))
          Next
        End If
      End If
    Next
  End If

  Wbk.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
Function VBCTypeNumToName(ByVal VBCType As Long) As String

  Select Case VBCType
    Case vbext_ct_StdModule                  '   1
      VBCTypeNumToName = "Module"
    Case vbext_ct_ClassModule                '   2
      VBCTypeNumToName = "Class Module"
    Case vbext_ct_MSForm                     '   3
      VBCTypeNumToName = "Form"
    Case vbext_ct_ActiveXDesigner            '  11
      VBCTypeNumToName = "ActiveX Designer"
    Case vbext_ct_Document                   ' 100
      VBCTypeNumToName = "Document Module"
  End Select

End Function
```

Comment: It would be simpler to save the files as `xlsx`.

Comment: Code is stopping and highlighting yellow this line "Dim VBC As VBComponent". Please help.

Comment: @ZafarIqbal  Have you obeyed the instructions at the top of the macro under the source references?  "This module needs a reference to: ..."  "The security system will probably prevent ..."

Comment: @brettdj  According to the question, the OP is using Excel 2003 so saving as XLSX is not an option.

Comment: @TonyDallimore Actually, OP said he/she had 500+ xls files but not that they were using - or were restricted to - xl03.

Comment: @brettdj True. Although I would still advise using the list component routine to create a backup.

Comment: Feedback is necessary so I want to get your attention once again, please. Tick Trust access to Visual Basic Project is already checked. Folder location at my PC is now shown as Path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\C:\Users\Zafar\Desktop\02\". This code is  giving run-time error '76': Path not found. Code is stuck at Set FolderObj = FileSysObj.GetFolder(Path). When I removed first back slash and run the code with Path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "C:\Users\Zafar\Desktop\02\", it says compile error: User-defined type is not defined, stopped & highlight "Dim VBC As VBComponent". Can you help to fix this error?

Comment: You want `Path = "C:\Users\Zafar\Desktop\02\"`. You are concatenating two separate paths together.

Comment: When you look at your references is "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility n.n" near the top of the list and ticked?  On my system, "n.n" is "5.3" but it may be different on yours. This library defines VBComponent.

Comment: Unfortunately, No Success with revision in path as advised. My PC has Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications 7.0 & MS Office 2010

Comment: @ZafarIqbal  I have created a folder "02" on my Desktop. If I replace your user name, Zafar, with mine then my code works as expected. My only theory is that the path to this folder is not quite what you expect. Open folder 02 with Windows Explorer. At the top you will see something like "» 02" where "»" represents a right-pointing triangle. On the right of the box containing "» 02" you will see a downward-pointing triangle. Click it. The "» 02" should be replaced by "C:\Users\Zafar\Desktop\02". Apart from the trailing "\", is this value **exactly** the same as the value in Path = "..."?

Comment: Thanks for your continuous guidance & patience. For simplicity I used Path = "\D:\Result\" in code. Result folder has BK-01.xls & BK-02.xls files. Code stopped at line Set FolderObj = FileSysObj.GetFolder(Path). When first \ is removed code creates a blank BkUp 141214 1103.txt file in folder, stops and highlights line Dim VBC As VBComponent. When I checked VB Object Browser Library, VBProject is present as Member but VBComponent is not available. Trust access to Visual Basic Project is already checked.

Comment: @ZafarIqbal  I guess `VBProject` is defined in several libraries. `VBComponent` is defined within `"Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility n.n"`  On my system n.n is "5.3" but I use an old version of Excel so you might have a later version.

Comment: As you discovered the leading "\" in "\D:\Result\" is invalid.